# Не отображается фотография

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, при попытке выбора фотографии из альбома, появляется ошибка: **Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error**
никак не могу понять где ошибка.
Swift 3 
Xcode 8.2

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                // imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }


      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
            imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            imagePost.image = image
        } else{
            print("Something went wrong")
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Попробуйте данный метод, надо проверить чтобы ваша картинка не была nil. Так же проверьте чтобы был установлен `delegate`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, использовал Ваш метод, все заработало, буду разбираться, что в моем коде пошло не так.

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правельный